# How to run long running synchronous operation in nodejs

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, pm2, event-loop, worker-thread

I am writing payroll management web application in nodejs for my organisation. In many cases application shall involve cpu intensive mathematical calculation for calculating the figures and that too with many users trying to do this simulatenously.

If i plainly write the logic (setting aside the fact that i already did my best from algorithm and data structure point of view to contain the complexity) it will run synchronously blocking the event loop and make request, response slow.

How to resolve this scenario? What are the possible options to do this **asynchronously**? I also want to mention that this calculation stuff can be let to run in the **background** and later i can choose to tell user via notification about the status. I have searched for the solution all over this places and i found some solutions but only in theory & i haven't tested them all by implementing. Mentioning below:

1. Clustering the node server
2. Use worker threads
3. Use an alternate server and do some load balancing.
4. Use a message queue and couple it with worker thread to do backgound tasks.

Can someone suggest me some tried and battle tested advice on this scenario? and also some tutorial links associated with that.

Answer (score -1):

You might wanna try web workers,easy to use and documented.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers